# acme/autocert listener reporting TLS handshake errors from unrecognized hosts

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

I use [acme/autocert](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert) to automatically handle TLS certifications for my server. It seems to have worked (in that my domain now has a valid TLS certificate), but I'm a bit confused on what else I'm seeing. My server log looks like this (note this is not the full log, just a selection):

```
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:44:49 http: TLS handshake error from 2.51.84.126:53282: acme/autocert: host "physicaldatebaby.org" not configured in HostWhitelist
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:44:50 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47416: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:44:55 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47418: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:01 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47420: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:06 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47422: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:07 http: TLS handshake error from 197.252.5.80:48622: read tcp 192.168.208.2:443->197.252.5.80:48622: read: connection reset by peer
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:11 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47424: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:16 http: TLS handshake error from 197.29.217.90:51215: acme/autocert: host "cloudfront.net" not configured in HostWhitelist
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:16 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47426: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:20 http: TLS handshake error from 156.172.18.24:21209: acme/autocert: host "paypal.com" not configured in HostWhitelist
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:21 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47428: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:27 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47430: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:32 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47432: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:37 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47434: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:42 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47436: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:47 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47438: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:52 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47440: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:45:58 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47442: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:03 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47444: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:08 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47446: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:13 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47448: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:14 http: TLS handshake error from 197.29.217.90:51572: acme/autocert: host "cloudfront.net" not configured in HostWhitelist
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:18 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47450: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:24 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47452: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:29 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47454: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:34 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47456: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:39 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47458: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:44 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47460: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:49 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47462: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:46:55 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47464: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:00 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47466: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:05 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47468: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:10 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47470: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:15 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47472: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:21 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47474: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:26 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47476: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:31 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47478: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:36 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47480: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:37 http: TLS handshake error from 197.149.220.123:31754: acme/autocert: host "cloudfront.net" not configured in HostWhitelist
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:41 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47482: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:47 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47484: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:52 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47486: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:47:57 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47488: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:48:02 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47490: acme/autocert: missing server name
rpc_1    | 2019/11/11 14:48:07 http: TLS handshake error from 92.5.192.229:47492: acme/autocert: missing server name
```

What is happening here? I want to leave this listener running so that my certificate renews but I'm worried about that log. I don't understand why those requests are coming through or how I can stop them. I've searched around but haven't been able to find any similar questions. These requests are not spawned from any clients I recognize, and one seems to be simply trying every single port it can from the same IP. I really don't know if this is appropriate for a production server, everything is up to date (it's running in the latest amazon EC2 ami) so I'm not sure if I'm at risk or need to take other measures. I'm a bit confused in general so I hope I can get some feedback to help cleanup this question.

My relevant Go code looks like this:

```golang
var endpoint = flag.String(
    "endpoint",
    os.Getenv("SERVER_ENDPOINT"),
    "Overwrite default endpoint defined in environment variables",
)

certManager := autocert.Manager{
    Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
    HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist(*endpoint),
    Cache:      autocert.DirCache("certs"),
}

// certManager.Listener() listens on 443
go http.Serve(certManager.Listener(), certManager.HTTPHandler(nil))
```

I have both port 80 and port 443 open to all inbound traffic, though I don't think I need 80 to be open to anything other than Lets Encrypt traffic (I think, my understanding of how Lets Encrypt works might be wrong?)

Comment: If you have a server on the public Internet you have to deal with spam requests. There's really not much else to say. "I don't think I need 80 to be open to anything other than Lets Encrypt traffic". Correct (if you don't need a redirect to https). Those logs are all results of TLS handshakes, though, so any kind of IP filter won't help you here. You probably *are* getting "weird" requests on port 80, you just don't log them.

Comment: The requests from 92.5.192.229 are worth investigating, because they are so regular. Some kind of health check that doesn't do SNI maybe?

Comment: That looks like a TCP healthcheck probe happening every 5 seconds. The healthcheck is a regular TCP connection and does not do TLS handshake, and you get these logs because of that.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, if it were a plain connection the error would be something like "first record does not look like a TLS handshake".

Comment: @Peter I am observing this behavior from my servers behind a TCP load balancer on aws. The load balancer health checks are causing this.

Comment: @Peter, fyi, according to aws docs, TCP health check for loadbalancer only performs a tcp connection. It does not initiate a tls handshake or send any other data. That probably explains the log msg.

Comment: @BurakSerdar unfortunately this container is not behind a load balancer, there is no health check happening as far as I am aware. The IP address is registered to TalkTalk communications so I don't think this is coming from amazon